# reading imports from text file in java/groovy

Tags: java, file, groovy, import

i would like to know if it is possible to somehow read data from a text file and use it to tell java what libaries to import. I dont think its possible in java but what about groovy?

Answer (score 1):

With groovy 1.8, it is possible to dynamically add imports to a script executed with GroovyShell.  In particular, take a look at [org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ImportCustomizer](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/ImportCustomizer.html).  There's a good example of how to use this here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/06/groovy-goodness-add-imports.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can't totally avoid having 'import' statements, but it is an important part of many implementations of dependency injection that the actual dependencies are defined in a config file (ie. external text) and this information is loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy has a "import handler",   class (interface to be true) `GroovyResourceLoader`, a kind of event is fired for every import required by "main" source. Is works in cooperation with `GroovyClassLoader` and maybe not with `GroovyShell`. I understand that my answer is in different area that "automatically add some hidden imports" - I speak about "classic imports".